# Using XML layout for TextView

Tags: android, layout, textview, xamarin, autolink

I use Xamarin and I have the following code:

```
base.OnCreate (bundle);

TextView textView = new TextView (this.ApplicationContext);
textView.AutoLinkMask = Android.Text.Util.MatchOptions.PhoneNumbers; 
textView.Text = "This is a phone number 0800 32 32 32";

//Linkify.AddLinks(textView, MatchOptions.PhoneNumbers);

SetContentView(textView);
```

Can I please have some help to do the same code but with resource layout files instead?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

textview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/txtView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="This is a phone number 0800 32 32 32"
android:autoLink="phone">
</TextView>
```

In onCreate just mention

```
setContentView(R.layout.textview);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/textview"
  android:text="This is a phone number 0800 32 32 32"
  android:autoLink="phone"
/>
```